# Difference between all_mviews and dba_mviews

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration, administrator

What is difference between `dba_mviews` and `All_mviews`?

They both give same result if we are running select query with system user.

Comment: The Oracle documentation answers this question (and many others asked on this site). [Find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-10024282-6729-4C66-8679-FD653C9C7DE7.htm#REFRN-GUID-10024282-6729-4C66-8679-FD653C9C7DE7)

Answer (score 4):

**USER_XYZ Views** -
Views that start with USER_ list only the objects owned by the currently logged in user.

**ALL_XYZ Views** - Views that start with ALL_ list only the objects the currently logged in user has permissions to access.

**DBA_XYZ Views** - Views that start with DBA_ list all objects.

While the USER_ and ALL_ views are always accessible, DBA_ views may or may not be, based on the privileges granted to specific users.

Since the System user has privileges to all tables, the result from the ALL_MVIEWS and DBA_MVIEWS is same. Try the same queries with a different user which doesn't have that much access.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big difference between two,

ALL_MVIEWS are those materialized views that are accessible to specific user &
DBA_MVIEWS are all the materialized views in whole database.